# "いまあたまがすっきりした", Is this phrase correct?

Tags: grammar, phrases, sentence

The context would be, "After traveling for two weeks, my mind is way clearer than before."

Answer (score 1):

今 means "now", and すっきりした is in the past tense. Therefore いまあたまがすっきりした means "My mind (just) clear**ed** up **now**!", which is a correct sentence but doesn't fit the previous context ("after traveling for two weeks"). To fix this, you can do either of the following:

- Just remove いま: あたまがすっきりした
- Keep いま and use the [teiru-form](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/3140/5010): いま(は)あたまがすっきりしている

Comment: Oh, i see~ ありがとうございます。：）